# Looking for a code that can extract data from a dataset only if all unique values of a column are available for unique values in another column

Tags: r

I am looking for a code in R where i can extract data from a dataset only if all unique values of a column are available for unique values in another column. For e.g:

```
Student  Month      Total
a        Jan        58
b        Jan        48
c        Jan        89
a        Feb        58
b        Feb        48
a        Mar        58
b        Mar        48
c        Mar        89
```

The code that is able to extract data for only those students whose marks for all months are available. In other words it should delete data if marks for all months are not available.

Thanks!
Kalo

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Student', `if` the `length` of the `unique` elements in 'Month' is equal to 12 (months in a calendar year), then output the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(Month)==12) .SD , by = Student]
```

Using the example showed by the OP, there are only 3 'Month's data, so it should be

```
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(Month)==uniqueN(df[["Month"]])) .SD , by = Student]
#    Student Month Total
#1:       a   Jan    58
#2:       a   Feb    58
#3:       a   Mar    58
#4:       b   Jan    48
#5:       b   Feb    48
#6:       b   Mar    48
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Student = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"c"), Month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", 
"Mar"), Total = c(58L, 48L, 89L, 58L, 48L, 58L, 48L, 89L)),
.Names = c("Student", "Month", "Total"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Hi.. thank you for the quick response. This really helps. What is the best way to get help on the above code.. or for that matter basic functions in R?